# Is it possible to pass the selector string for an angular Directive so that this directive is generic for multiple components

Tags: angular, selector, angular-directive

so I'm creating a directive to test the value of some field (i.e) an inputfield.

What I'm trying to figure out is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'toi-text-field input'
})
export class InputCheckDirective {
 @Input() color: string;
 @Input() minValue: number;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
   }
}
```

in here you can see that the selector is 'toi-text-field input' which will target the input element within the toi-text-field component.

Now what I was looking for is a way to pass this selector string some way (possibly as an inputvalue) so that I can determine on a higher level what element to look for 
for example:

```
'article p'
```

so that the directive will look for a p element within the article

cheers!

my element : (which is encapsulated by)

```
<toi-text-field> ... comp ... </toi-text-field>


<label
  *ngIf="label"
  class="toi-textfield__label"
  for="{{id}}">
  {{label}}
</label>
<input
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  [ngModelOptions]="modelOptions"
  (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)"
  type="text"
  class="toi-textfield__input"
  placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
  [color]="color"
  [minValue]="minValue"
  [disabled]="disabled">
```

My directive:

in here I set the colour of the text to red if the value in the inputfield is lower than the minValue

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, HostListener, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'toi-text-field input'
})
export class InputCheckDirective {
 @Input() color: string;
 @Input() minValue: number;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
   }
   @HostListener('blur') onBlur(): void {
     console.log('in blur');
     console.log(this.el);
    if (Number(this.el.nativeElement.attributes[4].value) < Number(this.minValue)) {
     this.el.nativeElement.style.color = this.color;
    } else {
     this.el.nativeElement.style.color = '#000';
 }
}

  @HostListener('focus') onfocus():void {

  }
}
```

I'm not getting error atm since I'm using a pre-defined selector but I was looking for a way to make this generic for any given element not only the input element.

Comment: Not clear to me! Do you need the control's minValue in the directive code?

Comment: actually the logic isnt really that important, what i want is to use this directive but not only for input fields, I'd like to use it for textarea's for example as well
But since the selector is 'toi-text-field input' , i can only use it for this component

it'd be super handy if i'd be able to say selector: 'inputstring'

so that  could say [inputstring]='div article p'

so the directive would do its work on the p element in the <div><article><p>here</p></article></div>

Comment: Then? Do you want to set color if the condition matches? Really unable to understand

Comment: the directive itself works, and does the job, for the component <toi-text-field><input> THIS INPUT VALUE IS CHECKED AND COLOR CHANGED</input></toi-text-field>

But lets say i make a new component <my-new-component> that has an element <textArea> and this textarea needs the have a similar check
how can i make it so that i can re-use my previously created directive  (so making the selectorstring an inputvalue or something)

Comment: I think the input directive should also work! Have you tried with text area?

Comment: it works when i change my selector in the directive.ts, but then it stops working for the input in my text-field-component

Comment: so im looking for a way to make the selector generic or to determine my selector through an inputvariable or something (sorry im trying to explain as best as i can)

Comment: Can you see this working here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4pf8b Might be can you explain it better?

Comment: Do you want to get the min value dynamically from directive input?

Comment: + for what you are using this? `Number(this.el.nativeElement.attributes[4].value)`?

Comment: usage of toy-text-field: (simplified)

 <toi-text-fieldt [color]="'red'" [minValue]='50' class="fixed-label"
                        [value]="pageDpi.value"
        </toi-text-field>

as you can see i dont have a keyword to determine my directive:
This because i use contentChildren() and the contentchild is the directive :

Comment: toi-text-field.component.ts:

export class ToiTextFieldComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input() minValue: number;
  @ContentChildren(InputCheckDirective) InputCheckDirective : 
  QueryList<InputCheckDirective>;
  
  constructor(){}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log('inputCheckDirective : ', this.InputCheckDirective);
  }
}

Comment: the directive used (InputCheckDirective) has a selector:

in this case: 
@Directive({
  selector: 'toi-text-field input'
})

Comment: Check this and let me know if you want this or else https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4pf8b

Comment: i want this selector to be determined through an input so that the directive is usable in other components aswell

Comment: i checked it but ur useing GenericInputDirective as selector and passing it to the element by doing <element GenericInputDirective>

Comment: Yes! Then.....? This how directives works

Comment: yes but you can also use it without the keyword by using a specific selector and passing the directive in contentChild (this way) i could use it in every component that has a contentChild of type directive (IF ofcourse im able to adjust the selector)

Comment: Give up from my side! Feel free to add a more and proper explanation in terms of expected output and current behaviour! n get back to me if required!

Comment: ok, thanks anyway for the trouble! ill try and figure it out or to put it more clearly